# How to redirect to URL unless some conditions is not met using HandlerInterceptor in a Spring Boot Web MVCApp

Tags: spring-mvc, redirect, spring-boot, interceptor

I am using Spring Boot for a WebMVC App.
There are many url that i serve in my app like

- /company
- /level
- /student
  etc.

Problem is 
How do i redirect to '/company' whenever any request is made and company has not yet been register.
I have tried using HandlerInterceptor like this

```
public class CompanySetupInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CompanySetupInterceptor.class);

CurrentUser currentUser;
@Autowired
CompanyService companyService;

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Object o) throws Exception {
    /*check company is registered or not
    * if not redirect to /company
    * */
    if(companyService.getCompany() == null){
        httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/company");
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

But every time i implement it,it goes into infinite loop from redirect to intercept and so on.
Localhost redirected you too many times.
[Localhost page is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXoCm.png)

How do i achieve solution to above problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interceptor you created is called for every incoming request and as you are redirecting to /company from your interceptor,its again an incoming request for spring mvc and is being forwarded again to interceptor thats why its going in infinite loop.

you need to configure your interceptor to bypass its execution for specific URL's like /company in your case.

Refer below link to configure interceptor 
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-interceptors